# I am getting Required argument [HttpServletResponse response] not specified when using HttpServletResponse as argument in my controller in micronaut

Tags: micronaut

Hi I am getting `Required argument [HttpServletResponse response] not specified` when I send request to my controller

```
public void getData(@QueryValue @NotNull String from,
                    HttpServletResponse response) {
}
```

Can someone help me around this

Comment: The response can't be injected as it is the result of your method. Are you mixing up request and response?

Comment: @SaschaFrinken My main use case is to write a file in the response itself, So I wanted this HttpServletResponse in my method argument so that I could use this response to write file directly in the response without saving it in any buffer. Any way out you could suggest me here?

Comment: in my request I am just sending one query param which is the "from" field as one of the argument

Comment: Sorry  my bad. I did not see that you are using servlet. The respons is injectable there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpResponse.ok(T body)` instead. This mentioned in documentation

> In addition, for full control over the emitted HTTP response you can use the static factory methods of the HttpResponse class which return a MutableHttpResponse.

[Micronaut Docs](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#requestResponse)